# How to get user specific time with a specific time and date

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to get the client machine local time.

I have to covert a specific UTC time to user's local time.

`2/10/2019 12:00:00 AM` -->> I have to convert this to user's time

I want to back the time to user's time.
Can tou please conver the time to user's time

Comment: What *time format* you need? EDIT: If you need to automatically get the user's local time. You can use ```-new Date(2/10/2019 12:00:00 AM).getTimezoneOffset()/60;```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `getTimezoneOffset` or `toLocaleString` or `toLocaleDateString`.

```js
const d = new Date('2/10/2019 12:00:00 AM');
const clientDate = d.toLocaleString();
const offset = d.getTimezoneOffset(); // offset in minutes
console.log({clientDate, offset});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use Date constructor of JS
if you want to get time for the current TimeZone you can use

```
const time = new Date().toUTCString();
```

or if you want to date according to some locale and time zone you can do something like this:

```
const locale = "en-US"; 
const  tz ="Australia/Sydney"
const current = new Date();
const options = {
  timeZone: tz,
  hour12: false,
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  second: "numeric"
};

const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, options);
const localTime = formatter.format(new Date());
```

Can read more about Date and Intl on MDN docs

INTL -https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl

Date - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assuming the specific UTC time is "2/10/2019 12:00:00 AM"
var utcTime = new Date("2019-02-10T00:00:00Z");

// Get the user's local time
var userTime = utcTime.toLocaleString();

console.log(userTime);
```